# Loop to create multiple boxplots in r. Why is only the last value of "i" applied to the calculation and position of significance letter?

Tags: r, loops, boxplot, anova, p-value

this is my first post, I hope to ask my question in the right place.
In summary, I have created a loop to create both boxplots of several species richness variables (rich_X) and associate ANOVA results via significance letters. My problem is as follows: as soon as I define my vector for the loop (loop.vector), the boxplots are correct, but the associated p-values and their position on the graph are based only on the last variable in the loop (here rich_10m). So I end up with three different boxplots (which are good) but with the same letters and the same positions, based on rich_10m.

Here is my code :

```
dataPDG<-read.csv2("donnees moyennes.csv")#my data
max_rich<-read.csv2("max_rich.csv")#will be used to calculate letters position on plots

loop.vector <- c("rich_tot","rich_2m","rich_10m")#the 3 variables 
plot_list<-list()

for (i in loop.vector) {
  x <- as.data.frame(dataPDG[, c("Stations", i)])#Stations contains 5 replicats 
  x[, 2] <- as.numeric(x[, 2])

  p <- ggboxplot(x, x = "Stations", y = i, color = "Stations", add = "jitter", legend = "none") +
    rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
    stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 13) +
    stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "anova", label.y = 12)
  
  max_values <- as.data.frame(max_rich[, c("Stations", i)])
  
  hsd <- HSD.test(aov(x[, 2] ~ Stations, data = x), trt = "Stations", group = T)
  sig.letter <- hsd$groups[order(row.names(hsd$groups)), ]
  sig.letter <- sig.letter[c("JD", "ES", "SG", "CC", "AO", "BA", "BO", "BR", "FE", "SN", "GF", "GP"), ]
  w <- max_values[[2]]
  
  d <- p + geom_text(data = max_values, aes(x = Stations, y = 0.5 + w, label = sig.letter$groups), vjust = 0)
  
  # Store the plot in the list with a name based on 'i'
  plot_list[[i]] <- d
}
plot_list[["rich_tot"]]
plot_list[["rich_2m"]]
plot_list[["rich_10m"]]
```

When I manually force the loop for a single variable (to check that the code is running correctly), no problems. It must came from sig.letter and w that are not updated correctly to i value.
Here is the none loop, working code :

```
dataPDG<-read.csv2("donnees moyennes.csv")#my data
max_rich<-read.csv2("max_rich.csv")#will be used to calculate letters position on plots

i<-"rich_tot"

  x <- as.data.frame(dataPDG[, c("Stations", i)])#Stations contains 5 replicats 
  x[, 2] <- as.numeric(x[, 2])

  p <- ggboxplot(x, x = "Stations", y = i, color = "Stations", add = "jitter", legend = "none") +
    rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
    stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 13) +
    stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "anova", label.y = 12)
  
  max_values <- as.data.frame(max_rich[, c("Stations", i)])
  
  hsd <- HSD.test(aov(x[, 2] ~ Stations, data = x), trt = "Stations", group = T)
  sig.letter <- hsd$groups[order(row.names(hsd$groups)), ]
  sig.letter <- sig.letter[c("JD", "ES", "SG", "CC", "AO", "BA", "BO", "BR", "FE", "SN", "GF", "GP"), ]
  w <- max_values[[2]]
  
  d <- p + geom_text(data = max_values, aes(x = Stations, y = 0.5 + w, label = sig.letter$groups), vjust = 0)
```

Do you have any idea where this might be coming from? Thanks a lot!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you get the same issue if instead of a loop you use `lappyl()`?

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you it worked. But i still don't why the loop failed.

Comment: Glad you got it working despite my typo (`lapply()`, for anyone coming to this later).  I haven't been through the loop in detail to work out why it didn't work, I just knew it wasn't how I would approach the issue, sorry!  (hence a comment not an answer).

Comment: Many portions of ggplot are "lazy" in that they only actually get components when you try to render it. This means that it gets some components after the loop, which means the values you're referencing have already been updated and represent the last values in your calculations. The use of `lapply` fixes this because in `lapply(..., function(i) ...)` the `i` is in a different environment each time, and since that's where the ggplot was created, it finds the correct version. In a `for` loop, it's typically `globalenv()` and therefore there is contention.

Comment: Since you adopted the suggested `lapply(` approach, publish your use of that as an answer so that others later can see how this simplified your route to successful execution, then accept.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for these comments.
to use lapply(), i have changed

```
loop.vector <- c("rich_tot","rich_2m","rich_10m")
plot_list<-list()
for (i in loop.vector) {
```

by

```
 plot_list_rich<-list()
 plot_list_rich <- lapply(c("rich_tot", "rich_2m", "rich_10m"), function(i) {
```

Final code :

```
plot_list_rich<-list()
plot_list_rich <- lapply(c("rich_tot", "rich_2m", "rich_10m"), function(i) {
  x <- as.data.frame(dataPDG[, c("Stations", i)])
  x[, 2] <- as.numeric(x[, 2])
p <- ggboxplot(x, x = "Stations", y = i, color = "Stations", add = "jitter", legend = "none") +
    rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
    stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 13) +
    stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "anova", label.y = 12) 
max_values <- as.data.frame(max_rich[, c("Stations", i)])
hsd <- HSD.test(aov(x[, 2] ~ Stations, data = x), trt = "Stations", group = T)
sig.letter <- hsd$groups[order(row.names(hsd$groups)), ]
sig.letter <- sig.letter[c("JD", "ES", "SG", "CC", "AO", "BA", "BO", "BR", "FE", "SN", "GF", "GP"), ]
w <- max_values[[2]]
d <- p + geom_text(data = max_values, aes(x = Stations, y = 0.5 + w, label = sig.letter$groups), vjust = 0)
return(d)
})
```

Thank you